# SET Variable not recognized inside Windows Batch File IN

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using Loop.bat to call copy.bat as given below

**Loop.bat**

```
FOR %%G IN (2 3 4) DO COPY.bat %%G
```

**Copy.bat**

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET DIR = C:\B%1_DATA\
for %%s in (^
 !DIR!B%1_File1.dat^
 !DIR!B%1_File2.dat )^
do xcopy /y %%s C:\Temp
```

The `%%S` appears as
`B2_File1.dat`

I want to append the directory path so that it becomes `C:\B2_DATA\B2_File1.dat`

Why isn't `DIR` variable not recognized inside for loop? I have also tried `%DIR%`.

Comment: because there is no variable `dir`. You defined a variable `dir `. Remove the spaces around `=`. They become part of the variable name / value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Stephan for pointing it out.
I removed space between `DIR` and = and its working now.